# Servicestack, Xamarin and authentication

Tags: authentication, xamarin, servicestack

I've got an ServiceStack service running with custom authentication, this runs fine from the browser and through a Windows console program.
I'm now trying to get a simple Xamarin Android program to authenticate but whatever I try it crashes with an Exception without any further explanation. The code I am using stops at the line with 'var authResponse', I'm using the 4.0.44 ServiceStack packages and the lastest stable Xamarin from inside VS2015.

```
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        // servicestack
        var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://10.0.2.2:8080");
        var authResponse = client.Get<AuthenticateResponse>( new Authenticate
        {
            UserName = "Willem",
            Password = "secret",
            RememberMe = true
        });
```

Any pointers to what/where I should look?
tia

Comment: You need to find out what the exception is, i.e. use a try/catch to log the error, or use a [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to view the raw HTTP Response.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the connection is refused for all clients that do not use 'http://localhost:8080' as the address.

Comment: If this is a self-hosted Service you would need to listen on `appHost.Start("http://*:8080");` to be able to accept requests from different hosts.

Comment: Brilliant, that solved he problem. I can now use my SQL database through a servicestack service on my Android emulator.

Comment: great glad to hear it, added solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a self-hosted Service you would need to register the HttpListener AppHost to accept requests from different hosts by listening on a host wildcard, e.g:

```
appHost.Start("http://*:8080/");
```